# Trying to hide irrelevant divs when relevant checkbox is not checked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following code where I have two requirements.

1. User should be able to check one checkbox. If they check 2nd checkbox, it should uncheck them from the first one.This is working for me based on the JS solution shown in the code below.
2. Only show checkbox related divs and hide other divs. This isn't working.

**NOTE:** For some reason, the select2() isn't working in the code snippet I've included below and hence it's not showing all the divs that shows up after checking a check box. Hence, I am including a [JSFiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/8g2p30s9/3/), which works fine and shows what I'm referring to. So please refer to the JSFiddle link as well to get the complete picture of my problem.

To address point #2 above, I am wondering if I need to switch to CSS classes to better handle showing divs and hiding divs instead of handling it via jQuery `.show()` and `.hide()` methods?

```js
//code to select only one checkbox
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
boxes.forEach(b => b.addEventListener("change", tick));
function tick(e) {
  let state = e.target.checked; // save state of changed checkbox
  boxes.forEach(b => b.checked = false); // clear all checkboxes
  e.target.checked = state; // restore state of changed checkbox
}

//Initialize select2
$("#availableLocations").select2();
$("#newLocation").select2();
$("#destinationLocation").select2();
$("#availableLocations").hide();
$("#forNewLocation").hide();
$("#retireLocationChange").hide();
$("#updateLocationChange").hide();
$("#markAsFullChange").hide();
$("#moveContentsChange").hide();

$("[name='changeLocation']").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#forNewLocation").show();
        $("#availableLocations").show();



    } else {
        $("#forNewLocation").hide();
        $("#availableLocations").hide();
    }
});


$("[name='retireLocation']").click(function() {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#retireLocationChange").show();
        $("#availableRetireLocations").show();
        $("#availableRetireLocations").select2();
    } else {
        $("#retireLocationChange").hide();
        $("#availableRetireLocations").hide();
    }
});

$("[name='updateLocation']").click(function() {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#updateLocationChange").show();
        $("#availableUpdateLocations").show();
        $("#availableUpdateLocations").select2();

        //Check if user selects something from the dropdown
        $("#availableUpdateLocations").change(function() {

            let locationVal = $(this).val();



        });


    } else {
        $("#updateLocationChange").hide();
        $("#availableUpdateLocations").hide();
    }
});

//mark as full
$("[name='markAsFull']").click(function() {

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#markAsFullChange").show();
        $("#availableMarkAsFullLocations").show();
        $("#availableMarkAsFullLocations").select2();
    } else {
        $("#markAsFullChange").hide();
        $("#availableMarkAsFullLocations").hide();
    }
});



$("#newLocation").change(function() {

    let selectedVal = $(this).val();
    $("#destinationLocation").empty();



});



/*FOR MOVE CONTENTS  */
$("[name='moveContents']").click(function() {

    console.log("Inside Move Contents");
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#moveContentsChange").show();
        $("#tierOneCheckBoxContents").hide();
        $("#tierTwoCheckBoxContents").hide();
        //For Tier One Selection
        $("[name='tierOneMove']").click(function() {

            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                console.log("Tier-I move selected");
                $("#tierOneCheckBoxContents").show();
                $("#availableTopLevelLocations").select2();
                $("#contentsInsidetopLevellocation").select2();
                $("#availableDestinationTopLevelLocations").select2();

                $("#contentsInsidetopLevellocation").empty();

                //User selects from the top level drop down ist
                $("#availableTopLevelLocations").change(function() {
                    let locationVal = $(this).val();
                    console.log(locationVal);
                    $("#contentsInsidetopLevellocation").empty();

                });

            } else {
                $("#tierOneCheckBoxContents").hide();
            }
        });



    } else {
        $("#moveContentsChange").hide();
    }
    //End: Tier One Block

    //Tier II move begins
    $("[name='tierTwoMove']").click(function() {


        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            console.log("Tier-II move selected");
            $("#tierTwoCheckBoxContents").show();

            $("#availableTopLevelLocationsforTierTwo").select2();
            $("#contentsInsidetopLevellocationfortiertwo").select2();
            $("#contentsInsidetopLevellocationfortiertwo").empty();
            //For multiselect 
            $("#tierThreeId").select2();
            //$('.multiple-select').multipleSelect()
            $("#availableDestinationLocationsforTierTwo").select2();
            //Empty Tier Two location
            $("#contentsInsidetopLevellocationfortiertwo").empty();
            //Empty Tier III location
            $("#tierThreeId").empty();

            //Tier-I location is selected
            $("#availableTopLevelLocationsforTierTwo").change(function() {
                let locationVal = $(this).val();
                console.log(locationVal);

                $("#contentsInsidetopLevellocationfortiertwo").empty();
                $("#tierThreeId").empty();


            });

            //Tier-II location is selected
            $("#contentsInsidetopLevellocationfortiertwo").change(function() {
                //When Tier II option is selected, popuate Tier III with its contents
                let locationVal = $(this).val();
                console.log(locationVal);


            });

            //Tier-III location is selected


        } else {
            $("#tierTwoCheckBoxContents").hide();
        }
    });




});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<form id="BuildingManageLocationForm" action="/buildingManageLocation.htm" method="POST">
   <div class="grid-center">
      <div>
         <label>Select one of the checkboxes:</label>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label><input id="changeLocation1" name="changeLocation" type="checkbox" value="true"><input type="hidden" name="_changeLocation" value="on">Change Location</label>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label><input id="updateLocation1" name="updateLocation" type="checkbox" value="true"><input type="hidden" name="_updateLocation" value="on">Update Location</label>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label><input id="retireLocation1" name="retireLocation" type="checkbox" value="true"><input type="hidden" name="_retireLocation" value="on">Retire</label>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label><input id="markAsFull1" name="markAsFull" type="checkbox" value="true"><input type="hidden" name="_markAsFull" value="on">Mark as full</label>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label><input id="moveContents1" name="moveContents" type="checkbox" value="true"><input type="hidden" name="_moveContents" value="on">Move Contents</label>
      </div>
      
      
      <div id="forNewLocation" style="display: none;">
         <label for="newLocation">Select the location type:</label>
         <select id="newLocation" name="newLocation" data-select2-id="select2-data-newLocation" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
            <option value="none" selected="" disabled="" data-select2-id="select2-data-4-6m16" hidden="">--Please Select--</option>
            <!-- <option value="Box">Box</option> -->
            <option value="Freezer">Freezer</option>
            <!-- <option value="BUILDING">BUILDING</option> -->
         </select>
         <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="select2-data-3-uqyc" style="width: 246.9px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-newLocation-container" aria-controls="select2-newLocation-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-newLocation-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="--Please Select--">--Please Select--</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
         <div>
            <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Select a current location:</label>
         </div>
         <div>
            <select id="availableLocations" name="availableLocations" data-select2-id="select2-data-availableLocations" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;">
               <option value="-" data-select2-id="select2-data-2-q76u">--Please Select--</option>
            </select>
            <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="select2-data-1-0azc" style="width: 246.9px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-availableLocations-container" aria-controls="select2-availableLocations-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-availableLocations-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="--Please Select--">--Please Select--</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Select a destination location:</label>
         </div>
         <div>
            <select id="destinationLocation" name="destinationLocation" data-select2-id="select2-data-destinationLocation" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
               <option value="-" data-select2-id="select2-data-6-9y2t">--Please Select--</option>
            </select>
            <span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default" dir="ltr" data-select2-id="select2-data-5-fkw9" style="width: 271.067px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-labelledby="select2-destinationLocation-container" aria-controls="select2-destinationLocation-container"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-destinationLocation-container" role="textbox" aria-readonly="true" title="--Please Select--">--Please Select--</span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="retireLocationChange" style="display: none;">
         <div>
            <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Select a location to retire:</label>
         </div>
         <div>
            <select id="availableRetireLocations" name="availableRetireLocations">
               <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
               <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
               <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
               <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
               <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
               <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
               
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="markAsFullChange" style="display: none;">
         <div>
            <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Select a location to mark as full:</label>
         </div>
         <div>
            <select id="availableMarkAsFullLocations" name="availableMarkAsFullLocations">
               <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
               <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
               <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
               <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
               <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
               <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
               
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="updateLocationChange" style="display: none;">
         <div>
            <label class="requiredFieldLabel">Select a location to update:</label>
         </div>
         <div>
            <select id="availableUpdateLocations" name="availableUpdateLocations">
               <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
               <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
               <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
               <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
               <option value="19">BOX#9</option>

            </select>
         </div>
         <div>
            <div><label>Update Name:</label></div>
            <div>
               <input id="updateLocationName" name="updateLocationName" type="text" value="" size="35" maxlength="100">
            </div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <div><label>Update Description:</label></div>
            <div>
               <textarea id="updateLocationDescription" name="updateLocationDescription" rows="2" cols="35"></textarea>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <div><label>Update Comment:</label></div>
            <div>
               <textarea id="updateLocationComment" name="updateLocationComment" rows="2" cols="35"></textarea>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div>
            <div><label>Update Capacity:</label></div>
            <div>
               <input id="updateCapacity" name="updateCapacity" type="text" value="" size="35" maxlength="100">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <style>
         select {
         width: 30%;
         }
      </style>
      <!-- <style>
         select {
           width: 100%;
         }
         </style>  -->
      <!--BEGIN: Move Contents   -->
      <div id="moveContentsChange" style="display: none;">
         <div>
            <label>Type of move:</label>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label><input id="tierOneMove1" name="tierOneMove" type="checkbox" value="true"><input type="hidden" name="_tierOneMove" value="on">Move contents within Tier-I locations:</label>
         </div>
         <div>
            <label><input id="tierTwoMove1" name="tierTwoMove" type="checkbox" value="true"><input type="hidden" name="_tierTwoMove" value="on">Move contents within Tier-II locations:</label>
         </div>
         <div id="tierOneCheckBoxContents">
            <div>
               <label>Select Tier-I location:</label>
            </div>
            <div>
               <select id="availableTopLevelLocations" name="availableTopLevelLocations">
                  <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
                  <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
                  <option value="21">BUILDING#1</option>
                  <option value="22">BUILDING#2</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div>
               <div><label>Select Tier-II location:</label></div>
               <div>
                  <select id="contentsInsidetopLevellocation" name="contentsInsidetopLevellocation">
                     <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div>
               <label>Select destination location:</label>
            </div>
            <div>
               <select id="availableDestinationTopLevelLocations" name="availableDestinationTopLevelLocations">
                  <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
                  <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
                  <option value="21">BUILDING#1</option>
                  <option value="22">BUILDING#2</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="tierTwoCheckBoxContents">
            <div>
               <label>Select Tier-I location:</label>
            </div>
            <div>
               <select id="availableTopLevelLocationsforTierTwo" name="availableTopLevelLocationsforTierTwo">
                  <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
                  <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
                  <option value="21">BUILDING#1</option>
                  <option value="22">BUILDING#2</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div>
               <div><label>Select Tier-II location:</label></div>
               <div>
                  <select id="contentsInsidetopLevellocationfortiertwo" name="contentsInsidetopLevellocationfortiertwo">
                  </select>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div>
               <div><label>Select Tier-III location:</label></div>
               <div>
                  <select id="tierThreeId" name="tierThreeId" multiple="multiple">
                     <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
                  </select>
                  <input type="hidden" name="_tierThreeId" value="1">
               </div>
            </div>
            <div>
               <label>Select destination location:</label>
            </div>
            <div>
               <select id="availableDestinationLocationsforTierTwo" name="availableDestinationLocationsforTierTwo">
                  <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
               </select>
            </div>
         </div>
         <!--END: Move Contents   -->
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
      <div class="buildingManageLocationButton">
         <button onclick="BuildingManageLocation(); return false">Save
         Your Changes</button>
      </div>
      <div>
         <span id="updateMessage" class="error"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: So to clear up my thoughts on this.  You are saying if box A is checked then box B is not a desire to use a Radio Button instead? That make Only one show up an HTML function.  Now for the other part:  Visible vs Hidden. 
h2.a {
  visibility: visible;
}

h2.b {
  visibility: hidden;
}

A show hide versus a hidden and visible setting on the visibility.

Comment: So if Box A is checked, I only want to show Box A-related divs.  The same goes for other boxes. I haven't been dealing with radio buttons here hence not saying anything about radio buttons here.

Comment: Chris's answer is pretty good.  Your complexity of your boxes and shows and hides might be better if it is simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very much over complicating things here.  Just use radio buttons instead of checkboxes since they are designed to only have one selected by default.

If you put the 2nd-tier options nearby each radio button then you can just show/hide the closest element instead of needing to keep track of ID's and states. Doing it this way you don't even have to put ID's on any elements either.

This is a much simplified example that doesn't contain all the options in your original question, but it's just to give the idea of how to simplify this down.

```js
$(".tier1-options :radio").on("change", function (e) {
  //remove shown class from all tier2 options and clear values from all form elements inside it
  $('.tier2-options')
    .removeClass('shown')
    .find('input, select').val('')
  
  //show the related tier2 options
  $(this)
    .parents('.tier1-options')
    .find('.tier2-options')
    .addClass('shown')
});
```

```css
.tier2-options {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.shown{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h5>Select one of the checkboxes:</h5>

<div class='tier1-options'>
  <label>
    <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="changeLocation">
    Change Location
  </label>

  <div class="tier2-options">
    <select name="availableMarkAsFullLocations">
      <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
      <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
      <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
      <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
      <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
      <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tier1-options">
  <label>
    <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="updateLocation">
    Update Location
  </label>

  <div class="tier2-options">
    <select name="availableUpdateLocations">
      <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
      <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
      <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
      <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
      <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="tier1-options">
  <label>
    <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="retireLocation">
    Retire
  </label>

  <div class="tier2-options">
    <select name="availableRetireLocations">
       <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
       <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
       <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
       <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
       <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
       <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you saying that I should only use `tier1-options` and `tier2-options` related div for my complex example? - class-related stuff that you have showed

Comment: I think so, yes. That will really simplify things by keeping related items near each other and not rely on mapping IDs to other IDs (like when checkbox `foo` is checked show the `bar` item).  Basically in the above code you'd only need to add in the specific options you need inside each of the `tier2-options` elements. All the code for hiding/showing/unselecting/clearing is already taken care of no matter how many there are.

Comment: Thanks. Your solutions have worked great so far but I have this problem. In one of the scenarios of `Move Contents` if you see above, I have check boxes inside checkboxes. So based on your solution, I get up to a point where I'm displaying two radio buttons after selecting the Move buttons radio button, can you tell me how to have the same solution for both the radio buttons inside the radio buttons? If you could please show by updating your code maybe. Thanks!

Comment: Here's my JSFiddle regarding what I'm trying to achieve based on above concern. https://jsfiddle.net/0wnkgpcv/1/

Comment: Radio buttons work together in a group if they share the same `name` value. You just need to have those radio buttons grouped separately. I've made a fork of your JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/a6v15gnc/ - All the "Tier 1 options" use `name="useroption"` and then the radio buttons in the "Move options" use `name="moveoption"` - You can name these whatever you want, just make the names match on the ones you want to be grouped together.

Comment: For some reason, the forked JSfiddle you shared (https://jsfiddle.net/a6v15gnc/) is not working as expected.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what is not expected? Click that link has functioning radio buttons on the top tier and then a separate set of radio buttons on the "move contents"  area.