# Trying to put radio buttons inside a radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Basically, I'm following [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76724363/trying-to-hide-irrelevant-divs-when-relevant-checkbox-is-not-checked/76724654?noredirect=1#comment135267334_76724654) and the following solution works fine if I have to display radio buttons and the and display divs inside it :

```js
$(".tier1-options :radio").on("change", function (e) {
  //remove shown class from all tier2 options and clear values from all form elements inside it
  $('.tier2-options')
    .removeClass('shown')
    .find('input, select').val('')
  
  //show the related tier2 options
  $(this)
    .parents('.tier1-options')
    .find('.tier2-options')
    .addClass('shown')
});
```

```css
.tier2-options {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #EEE;
}

.shown{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h5>Select one of the checkboxes:</h5>

<div class='tier1-options'>
  <label>
    <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="changeLocation">
    Change Location
  </label>

  <div class="tier2-options">
    <select name="availableMarkAsFullLocations">
      <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
      <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
      <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
      <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
      <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
      <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="tier1-options">
  <label>
    <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="updateLocation">
    Update Location
  </label>

  <div class="tier2-options">
    <select name="availableUpdateLocations">
      <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
      <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
      <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
      <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
      <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="tier1-options">
  <label>
    <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="retireLocation">
    Retire
  </label>

  <div class="tier2-options">
    <select name="availableRetireLocations">
       <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
       <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
       <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
       <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
       <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
       <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I'm trying to add multiple radio buttons, this code isn't working for `Move Contents` option. Basicaly the `subtier2-options` won't show up when I click on `Tier I Move` or `Tier II Move`

```js
$(".tier1-options :radio").on("change", function (e) {
      //remove shown class from all tier2 options and clear values from all form elements inside it
      $('.tier2-options')
        .removeClass('shown')
        .find('input, select').val('')
      
      //show the related tier2 options
      $(this)
        .parents('.tier1-options')
        .find('.tier2-options')
        .addClass('shown')
    });
    
    $(".subtier1-options :radio").on("change", function (e) {
      //remove shown class from all tier2 options and clear values from all form elements inside it
      $('.subtier2-options')
        .removeClass('shown')
        .find('input, select').val('')
      
      //show the related tier2 options
      $(this)
        .parents('.subtier1-options')
        .find('.subtier2-options')
        .addClass('shown')
    });
```

```css
    .tier2-options {
      display: none;
      margin-left: 1rem;
      padding: 1rem;
      background-color: #EEE;
    }

    .shown{
      display: block;
    }
    
    .subtier2-options {
      display: none;
      margin-left: 1rem;
      padding: 1rem;
      background-color: #EEE;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <h5>Select one of the checkboxes:</h5>

    <div class='tier1-options'>
      <label>
        <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="changeLocation">
        Change Location
      </label>

      <div class="tier2-options">
        <select name="availableMarkAsFullLocations">
          <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
          <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
          <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
          <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
          <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
          <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tier1-options">
      <label>
        <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="updateLocation">
        Update Location
      </label>

      <div class="tier2-options">
        <select name="availableUpdateLocations">
          <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
          <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
          <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
          <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
          <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="tier1-options">
      <label>
        <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="retireLocation">
        Retire
      </label>

      <div class="tier2-options">
        <select name="availableRetireLocations">
           <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
           <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
           <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
           <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
           <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
           <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='tier1-options'>
      <label>
        <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="moveContents">
        Move Contents
      </label>

        <div class="tier2-options">
             <div class='subtier1-options'>
                 <label>
                  <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="moveContentsTierI">
                  Tier I move
                </label>

                 <div class="subtier2-options">
                     <select name="availableTierILocations">
                     <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
                     <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
                     <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
                     <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
                     <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
                     <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
                  </select>
                 
                 </div>
                
             
             </div> <!--end of <div class='subtier1-options'> -->
             
             <div class='subtier1-options'>
                 <label>
                  <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="moveContentsTierII">
                  Tier II move
                </label>

                 <div class="subtier2-options">
                     <select name="availableTierIILocations">
                     <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
                     <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
                     <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
                     <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
                     <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
                     <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
                  </select>
                 
                 </div>
                
             
             </div> <!--end of <div class='subtier1-options'> -->
             
             
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use classes within the css file, the classes are applied in the order that they are written. Since the `shown` class is above the `subtier2-options` class, it gets applied first. So, display is set to `block` and then changed to `none`, when `subtier2-options` is applied.

You just have to change the order of the classes within the css, as below, and then it works.

```js
$(".tier1-options :radio").on("change", function (e) {
      //remove shown class from all tier2 options and clear values from all form elements inside it
      $('.tier2-options')
        .removeClass('shown')
        .find('input, select').val('')
      
      //show the related tier2 options
      $(this)
        .parents('.tier1-options')
        .find('.tier2-options')
        .addClass('shown')
    });
    
    $(".subtier1-options :radio").on("change", function (e) {
      //remove shown class from all tier2 options and clear values from all form elements inside it
      $('.subtier2-options')
        .removeClass('shown')
        .find('input, select').val('')
      
      //show the related tier2 options
      $(this)
        .parents('.subtier1-options')
        .find('.subtier2-options')
        .addClass('shown')
    });
```

```css
    .tier2-options {
      display: none;
      margin-left: 1rem;
      padding: 1rem;
      background-color: #EEE;
    }
    
    .subtier2-options {
      display: none;
      margin-left: 1rem;
      padding: 1rem;
      background-color: #EEE;
    }

    .shown{
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <h5>Select one of the checkboxes:</h5>

    <div class='tier1-options'>
      <label>
        <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="changeLocation">
        Change Location
      </label>

      <div class="tier2-options">
        <select name="availableMarkAsFullLocations">
          <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
          <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
          <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
          <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
          <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
          <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tier1-options">
      <label>
        <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="updateLocation">
        Update Location
      </label>

      <div class="tier2-options">
        <select name="availableUpdateLocations">
          <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
          <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
          <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
          <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
          <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="tier1-options">
      <label>
        <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="retireLocation">
        Retire
      </label>

      <div class="tier2-options">
        <select name="availableRetireLocations">
           <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
           <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
           <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
           <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
           <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
           <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class='tier1-options'>
      <label>
        <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="moveContents">
        Move Contents
      </label>

        <div class="tier2-options">
             <div class='subtier1-options'>
                 <label>
                  <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="moveContentsTierI">
                  Tier I move
                </label>

                 <div class="subtier2-options">
                     <select name="availableTierILocations">
                     <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
                     <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
                     <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
                     <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
                     <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
                     <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
                  </select>
                 
                 </div>
                
             
             </div> <!--end of <div class='subtier1-options'> -->
             
             <div class='subtier1-options'>
                 <label>
                  <input name="useroption" type="radio" value="moveContentsTierII">
                  Tier II move
                </label>

                 <div class="subtier2-options">
                     <select name="availableTierIILocations">
                     <option value="-">--Please Select--</option>
                     <option value="3">BOX#3</option>
                     <option value="6">FREEZER#1</option>
                     <option value="8">FREEZER#2</option>
                     <option value="19">BOX#9</option>
                     <option value="20">QBUILDING</option>
                  </select>
                 
                 </div>
                
             
             </div> <!--end of <div class='subtier1-options'> -->
             
             
        </div>
    </div>
```